# MySQL,How To Get Part of Text

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have mysql result like this

```
<a href="http://host/folder/asset/uploads/2015/05/2.jpg">
       <img class="aligncenter wp-image-2470 " src="http://host/folder/asset/uploads/2015/05/2.jpg" alt="2" width="800" height="439" />
</a>
```

but the result that I need is like this

```
<img class="aligncenter wp-image-2470 " src="http://host/folder/asset/uploads/2015/05/2.jpg" alt="2" width="800" height="439" />
```

I have some mysql syntax like this

```
CONCAT('<img ',SUBSTRING_INDEX(news_content,'<img',-1),SUBSTRING_INDEX(news_content,'/>',1)),
```

but its not working
I need only the  tag only, can you help me please?thank you very much

Comment: This would be considerably easier with a programming language of some kind that had a proper HTML parser in it. MySQL does not have such a facility.

Comment: @tadman very well thanks

Comment: Here's an idea https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b3619676f3e1d7521d4e76db7127620f but it's not something that definitely will work. It depends heavily on the right condition that you define.

Comment: I never understood why people save HTML in a relational database. That makes no sense in any case